# How do I configure monit to allow the change in pid?

Tags: capistrano, sidekiq, monit

I am deploying a rails app with sidekiq. On each deploy Capistrano stops a previous running version of sidekiq (a ruby process) and then starts a new one. I am monitoring the sidekiq pid file with monit.

Problem: Each time I deploy the pid file changes but monit detects that it has changed and restarts the process. Over the period of a few days and multiple releases I end up with multiple sidekiq instances when I only want one.

Here is my monit config for sidekiq:

```
check process sidekiq_main with pidfile /srv/apps/orders/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
  every 3 cycles
  start program = "/bin/bash -c -l 'cd /srv/apps/orders/current ; nohup bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C /srv/apps/orders/current/config/sidekiq.yml -i 0 -P /srv/apps/orders/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid >> /srv/apps/orders/current/log/sidekiq.log 2>&1 &'"
  stop program  = "/bin/bash -c -l 'cd /srv/apps/orders/current ; bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /srv/apps/orders/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid 10'"
  group sidekiq
```

Is there a way to configure monit to allow for the pid file to change and only make sure that a sidekiq instance is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the default capistrano task to ensure that restarting sidekiq is done through monit.

For example, you could add this to your deploy.rb

```
namespace :sidekiq do    
  desc "Restart sidekiq"
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :on_no_matching_servers => :continue do
    run "sudo /usr/bin/monit restart sidekiq"
  end
end
```